# How to download song using discord.py to device locally?

Tags: discord.py, youtube-dl

I want to add a command like `!download song_name` to download song on device.

And I am thinking of using youtube_dl but I couldn't figure out how to implement so that it would download to local storage (memory card of phone)?

How can we download to device without or simultaneously downloading in server?

And how could we actually download it to device?
(I searched online but couldn't find the answer, please help!)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def download(ctx, url:str):

  ydl_opts = {
              'format': 'bestaudio/best',
              'preferredcodec': [{
                  'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                  'preferredcodec': 'webm',
                  'preferredquality': '192',
          }],
          }
  
  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: thanks, it downloaded, and  you tube is closing music bots, do you know any free alternatives of you tube for playing music using discord bot?

Comment: you can use persian bot  for youtube :
https://discord.bots.gg/bots/735403725132136510
@AanandaGiri

Comment: Thank you, It's good..

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make a command to download a video or file onto a USERS current device using youtube-dl, what you CAN do is maybe download the song_name and then upload the converted file to the channel so that the user can download it onto their device.

To clarify: youtube-dl will download a youtube video link onto the HOST machine (the computer that the discord.py bot is running on)

Comment: Thanks! and you tube is closing music bots, do you know any free alternatives of you tube for music?

Comment: Discord is closing big music bots, if you make one just for your server they probably wont close it, unless you add a "premium" to it